# Python Image pop up for 5 seconds

Tags: python, image

I am trying to show pop up of image in python for 5 seconds when a certain criteria matches in the function.

```
Img=Image.open('D:\\Capture.PNG')
Img.show()
```

But this code opens a image in windows photo viewer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you expect the image to pop-up (assuming you're running your script from a command-line shell). By default `PIL` uses whatever application is associated with images on your system when you use `Img.show()`. If you want something different, you're going to need to write it yourself. One possibility is to use the [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter) module.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

ImageAddress = '/home/yourfolder/yoursample.jpg'
ImageItself = Image.open(ImageAddress)
ImageNumpyFormat = np.asarray(ImageItself)
plt.imshow(ImageNumpyFormat)
plt.draw()
plt.pause(5) # pause how many seconds
plt.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The only issue I seem to have with this code is that the images don't come to the forefront of the screen, any thoughts on this?